# Postgres json query

Tags: postgresql

I have a field of type json which contains the following value

```
[
{"description": "example"},
{"description": "one"},
{"description": "two"},
]
```

how can I write a query that filters for "description" = "two"?

Would I only like the lines that contain "description" = "two"?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try [any of the json operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) `@>`

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column @> '[{"description": "two"}]'
```

If your column is defined as `json` rather than `jsonb` (which it should be), you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d7bd55b9359361028b70ee1b0e9736f6)